# Android is returning <null> for the phone number

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, abstract-class, phone-number

I have been doing a project in order to get the data of incoming calls, outgoing calls, and the corresponding phone number based on the state of a phone. The main class is as follows:

```
package com.example.phonecallreceiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Date;

public abstract class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static int LastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
public static Date CallStartTime;
public boolean isIncoming;
public static String SavedNumber;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")){

        String SavedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");  // Get
        Log.i(PhoneCallReceiver.class.getSimpleName(), "New Outgoing Call" + SavedNumber);

    } else{

        String SavedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        String stateSTR = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        int state = 0;

        if(stateSTR.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){

             state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;

        } else if(stateSTR.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){

             state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;

        } else if(stateSTR.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){

             state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;

        }

            onCallStateChanged(context, state, SavedNumber);

    }

}

protected void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String Number){

    switch (state){

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

            isIncoming = true;
            SavedNumber = Number;
            CallStartTime = new Date();
            onIncomingCallStarted(context, SavedNumber, CallStartTime);

            break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

            // Ringing > OffHook: Incoming Call
            if(LastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){

                SavedNumber = Number;
                isIncoming = true;
                CallStartTime = new Date();
                onIncomingCallStarted(context, SavedNumber, CallStartTime);

            // Idle > OffHook: Outgoing Call
            } else if(LastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){

                isIncoming = false;
                CallStartTime = new Date();
                SavedNumber = Number;
                onOutgoingCallStarted(context, SavedNumber, CallStartTime);

            }

            break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:

                // Ringing > Idle: MissedCall
                if(LastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){

                    SavedNumber = Number;
                    CallStartTime = new Date();
                    isIncoming = true;
                    onMissedCall(context, SavedNumber, CallStartTime);

                    // OffHook > Idle: onCallEnded
                } else if(LastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){

                    if(isIncoming){

                        onIncomingCallEnded(context, SavedNumber, CallStartTime);

                    } else{

                        onOutcomingCallEnded(context, SavedNumber, CallStartTime);
                    }

                    SavedNumber = Number;
                    CallStartTime = new Date();

                }

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    LastState = state;

}

protected abstract void onIncomingCallStarted(Context context, String Number, Date date);
protected abstract void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context context, String Number, Date date);
protected abstract void onMissedCall(Context context, String Number, Date date);
protected abstract void onIncomingCallEnded(Context context, String Number, Date date);
protected abstract void onOutcomingCallEnded(Context context, String Number, Date date);

} // PhoneCallReceiver
```

And the extender class is as follows:

```
package com.example.phonecallreceiver;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyReceiver extends PhoneCallReceiver{

protected static final String Tag = MyReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context context, String Number, Date date) {

    Log.i(Tag, "Incoming : Started < " + Number + ">");

}

@Override
protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context context, String Number, Date date) {

    Log.i(Tag, "Outcoming : Started < " + Number+ ">");

}

@Override
protected void onMissedCall(Context context, String Number, Date date) {

    Log.i(Tag, "MissedCall < " + Number + ">" + date);

}

@Override
protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context context, String Number, Date date) {

    Log.i(Tag, "IncomingCall Ended... >" + Number);
}

@Override
protected void onOutcomingCallEnded(Context context, String Number, Date date) {

    Log.i(Tag, "OutcomingCall Ended... >" + Number);

}
}
```

I have also been granted the required permissions to use Phone states. The problem I'm dealing with is that in the Run window, the phone number is not displayed and the android returns `<null>` as the phone number. Why is it so?
The Run window is something like this:

```
I/MyReceiver: Incoming : Started < null>
W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
I/MyReceiver: MissedCall < null>Sat May 06 11:56:16 GMT+03:30 2023
I/MyReceiver: Incoming : Started < null>
I/MyReceiver: Incoming : Started < null>
I/MyReceiver: OutcomingCall Ended... >null
```